# Protobuf compiler for Go structs not generating the right package name for imports?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, go-modules, protoc

Consider the following example project with Go module `github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example` and the following directory structure (with `.proto` files in the `proto` directory and generated Go code in `gen/go`):

```
.
├── gen
│   └── go
│       ├── author
│       │   └── author.pb.go
│       └── book
│           └── book.pb.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── proto
    ├── author
    │   └── author.proto
    └── book
        └── book.proto
```

Here `author.proto` reads

```
syntax="proto3";
package author;

message Author {
    string name = 1;
}
```

and `book.proto` imports `author.proto` like so:

```
syntax="proto3";
package book;

import "author/author.proto";

message Book {
    string title = 1;
    author.Author author = 2;
}
```

I've generated the `.pb.go` files by, in the `proto/` directory, running

```
protoc book/book.proto --go_out=../gen/go
```

and

```
protoc author/author.proto --go_out=../gen/go
```

The problem is that the package name under which `author` is imported in `book.pb.go` is simply `"author"`:

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: book/book.proto

package book

import (
    author "author"
    fmt "fmt"
    proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    math "math"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ = proto.Marshal
var _ = fmt.Errorf
var _ = math.Inf

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the proto package it is being compiled against.
// A compilation error at this line likely means your copy of the
// proto package needs to be updated.
const _ = proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3 // please upgrade the proto package

type Book struct {
    Title                string         `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=title,proto3" json:"title,omitempty"`
    Author               *author.Author `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=author,proto3" json:"author,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}       `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte         `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32          `json:"-"`
}

func (m *Book) Reset()         { *m = Book{} }
func (m *Book) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*Book) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*Book) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_ee9082fb44230b1b, []int{0}
}

func (m *Book) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Book.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *Book) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Book.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *Book) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_Book.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *Book) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Book.Size(m)
}
func (m *Book) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_Book.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_Book proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *Book) GetTitle() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Title
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *Book) GetAuthor() *author.Author {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Author
    }
    return nil
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterType((*Book)(nil), "book.Book")
}

func init() { proto.RegisterFile("book/book.proto", fileDescriptor_ee9082fb44230b1b) }

var fileDescriptor_ee9082fb44230b1b = []byte{
    // 108 bytes of a gzipped FileDescriptorProto
    0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xff, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0x4f, 0xca, 0xcf, 0xcf,
    0xd6, 0x07, 0x11, 0x7a, 0x05, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x25, 0xf9, 0x42, 0x2c, 0x20, 0xb6, 0x94, 0x70, 0x62,
    0x69, 0x49, 0x46, 0x7e, 0x91, 0x3e, 0x84, 0x82, 0x48, 0x29, 0xb9, 0x70, 0xb1, 0x38, 0xe5, 0xe7,
    0x67, 0x0b, 0x89, 0x70, 0xb1, 0x96, 0x64, 0x96, 0xe4, 0xa4, 0x4a, 0x30, 0x2a, 0x30, 0x6a, 0x70,
    0x06, 0x41, 0x38, 0x42, 0x6a, 0x5c, 0x6c, 0x10, 0xd5, 0x12, 0x4c, 0x0a, 0x8c, 0x1a, 0xdc, 0x46,
    0x7c, 0x7a, 0x50, 0xcd, 0x8e, 0x60, 0x2a, 0x08, 0x2a, 0x9b, 0xc4, 0x06, 0x36, 0xcc, 0x18, 0x10,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x2c, 0x89, 0x1f, 0x45, 0x7a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
}
```

I would like the generated go code to instead import each other with the correct package name, so that `book.pb.go` would start like this:

```
package book

import (
    fmt "fmt"
    math "math"

    proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    author "github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example/gen/go/author"
)
```

How can I make the Protobuf compiler 'aware' of the Go module the generated code is in?

(I suspect that I need to specify the `option go_package` (cf. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial), but doing so doesn't seem to alter the generated code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! I suspect you may be bitten by relative paths...

---

Provided your proto files begin something like this:

```
package author;
option go_package = "github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example/gen/go/author";
```

and

```
package book;
import "author/author.proto";
option go_package = "github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example/gen/go/book";
```

and using build commands (with *relative* paths)

```
mkdir -p gen/go
protoc book/book.proto --go_out=gen/go
protoc author/author.proto --go_out=gen/go
```

your generated code will appear at these **relative** paths (to your CWD):

```
gen/go/github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example/gen/go/author/author.pb.go
gen/go/github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example/gen/go/book/book.pb.go
```

The generated `book` package should have the desired import:

```
package book

import (
        fmt "fmt"
        proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
        author "github.com/kurtpeek/proto-example/gen/go/author"
        math "math"
)
```

---

If you want your generated code placed in a specific directory, use an absolute path:

```
mkdir -p /some/absolute/path
protoc my.proto --go_out=/some/absolute/path
```